# Is there an automated mechanism where I can detect if any email field is missing?

Tags: asp.net-core

Let's assume this class:

```
public class AccountInfo
{
    public string   Email;
    public string   Username;
    public string   Password;
}
```

and this ASP api:

```
[HttpPost, Route("create")]
public IActionResult CreateUser([FromBody]AccountInfo Info)
{
    ...
}
```

If a user passes something like this:

```
{
    "eail" : "ndienw",    <--- notice the mispelling
    "username" : "djiw",
    "password" : "dow"
}
```

The email field will be null, so I need in each call to check for every fields.

Is there an automated mechanism where I can detect if any field is missing? I'm looking for something generic that can be applied through all calls.
Being able to opt out and mark some parameters optional would be great, but in our case, everything is always needed so far.

In this scenario, the ModelState is still valid; is that the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data annotations on your Email property. RegularExpression attribute will check the field that located on, whether the value which provided is matching with this pattern. Required attribute checks whether this field is empty or not.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Email was invalid.")]
[Required]
public string Email;
```

Comment: what I am looking for is a generic mechanism that intercepts every API and makes sure that every parameter is provided; I'm trying to not have to explicitly mark all fields are required.